# Apache rewrite "domain.com/folder" to "folder.domain.com" with keeping redirection from "folder.domain.com" to "domain.com/folder"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I want `folder.domain.com` to point at `domain.com/folder`

and

I want `domain.com/folder` to be rewritten in the URL of page in the browser to `folder.domain.com`.

In both cases I want to see an URL like this `folder.domain.com`.

Tried:

```
Redirect 301 /subdomain http://subdomain.example.com
```

Neither work:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /ucp/profile\.php?([^=]+)=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ucp/profile\.php$ /ucp/%1/%2? [R=301,L,NC]

# Now, deal with internal rewrites (which will not cause redirection):
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ucp/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /ucp/profile.php?$1=$2 [NC,L]
enter code here
```

And many many more.

Is it even achievable?

Comment: does request domain.com/whatever being folder.domain.com/folder/whatever or just folder.domain.com/whatever?

Comment: I just want to redirect folder.domain.com to domain.com/folder, but leave only folder.domain.com in url bar